# Format Phone Number inside of concat field SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a unique circumstance here. I have a concatenated field I call address and as part of this address I have the phone number of that address on the last line. currently the phone number is formatted like:

```
8885551212
```

I want it to format like:

```
(888) 555-1212
```

Below is my INSERT into my temp table that I do for getting everything correct. Any guidance on how to get the phone portion working right is a great help. I did find one article talking about using a function but I am unsure how to write it up properly for my circumstance. Thank you.

```
INSERT into #Referral_Temp (status, physician, timeFrame, date, address)
    select o.actStatus, o.actTextDisplay, apptTimeframe, apptDate,
    (select (p.address_line_1 + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + p.address_line_2 + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
             + p.city + ', ' + p.state + ' ' + p.zip + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + p.phone) 
             AS address)
    from order_ o
    join provider_mstr p on o.refer_to_prov_id = p.provider_id
    where o.encounterID = @enc_id
```

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: too bad it is not 2012 or higher, you could have used `FORMAT()` function. Which makes things like this very easy. `SELECT FORMAT(8885551212,'(000) 000-0000')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SUBSTRING function:

change

```
+ p.phone
```

to

```
+ '(' + SUBSTRING(p.phone,1,3) + ') ' 
+ SUBSTRING(p.phone,4,3) + '-' 
+ SUBSTRING(p.phone,7,4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`Stuff`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188043.aspx)** string function to insert the required special into the string. Try this.

```
SELECT '('+ Stuff(Stuff('8885551212', 4, 0, ') '), 9, 0, '-')
```

Comment: Suggest change of `')'), 8, 0, '-')` to `') '), 9, 0, '-')`. Then it'll match OP format exactly

Comment: @AeroX - Sorry missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT '(' + SUBSTRING('8885551212',1,3) + ') ' + SUBSTRING('8885551212',4,3) + '-' + SUBSTRING('8885551212',7,4)
```

Output will be :- (888) 555-1212